# Dynamic Show Morrise.js Hover Label On select datepicker value

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I need to When changing **the month on the calendar** it reflects in the statistics chart to **show the line** and number of selected moth .
I use **"bootstrap date-picker"** 
*if u have another chart suggestions let me know please.*

like this :

[image]image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- find index of selected date in your data provider when a date selected in datepicker.

2- use `morris.displayHoverForRow(index)` method to hover on that item.

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ercanpeker/t6ygeud0/

note: i used jQuery UI datepicker.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, I did not know that function!

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone use bootsrap datepicker that's My Code :

```
 $("#calendar").datepicker({
  format: "dd MM yyyy",
})
.on('changeDate', function (e) {
  currMonth = months[new Date(e.date).getMonth()];
  console.log(currMonth);
  var index = e.date.getMonth()
  if (index != -1) {
    _chart.displayHoverForRow(index)
  }

});
```